# Fable.Reactstrap not defined on Client fsproj SATE-stack

Tags: f#, fable-f#, elmish, safe-stack

I'm trying to use `Fable.Reactstrap` on Client project from [SAFE.Template](https://github.com/SAFE-Stack/SAFE-template/tree/master/Content/default). I've added `Fable.Reactstrap` to Nuget, Paket, and NPM but still receive `error FSHARP: The namespace 'Reactstrap' is not defined` when executing `dotnet run`. It's an error from code:

```
open Fable.Reactstrap
```

The real code can be found on my [github's repo](https://github.com/rizaramadan/safestack-realworld-example-app/blob/2e4afcade0ebeb9bf6d749994eeabf9279d475aa/src/Client/Index.fs#L5). `Fable.Reactstrap` itself has been added to project's dependencies and added in `paket.references`.

How can I resolve this error and user `Fable.Reactstrap` in my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The namespace is just `Reactstrap`, so this should work:

```ml
open Reactstrap
```

See example code [here](https://nojaf.com/fable-reactstrap/components/alerts).

Comment: Ah, why I didn't think of looking at reactstrap sample, thanks!